# Heroku ActionView::Template::Error Precompile Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I've been battling this issue for one of my sites for over a day. I've pushed several sites to Heroku but this one (which works fine locally) constantly gives me a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message on Heroku.

When I look at the Heroku Logs this is what I see:

```
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:24385
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-25 20:29:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-25 20:29:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=24385
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-01-25 20:29:42] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
    2013-01-25T20:29:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2013-01-25T20:29:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
    2013-01-25T20:29:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
    2013-01-25T20:29:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
    2013-01-25T20:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 198.207.185.100 at 2013-01-25 20:30:50 +0000
    2013-01-25T20:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PeopleController#index as HTML
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered people/index.html.erb within layouts/application (40.2ms)
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/people/index.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_people_index_html_erb__54318736437858219_34439980'
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 299ms
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     37:                                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="lightbox" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     42:                           </div>
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     38:                               </div>
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     39:                               <div class='lightbox-content'>
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/people/index.html.erb:40:in `block in _app_views_people_index_html_erb__54318736437858219_34439980'
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     40:                                   <%=image_tag person.map %>
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     43:                           <!-- end lightbox code -->
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/people_controller.rb:7:in `index'
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/people/index.html.erb:25:in `each'
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-01-25T20:30:51+00:00 app[web.1]:     41:                               </div>
```

The key problem I'm seeing above is "ActionView::Template::Error"

I've run

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and compiled my assets multiple times. (including deleting the contents of my Public Assets directory.

I've read that the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem should be moved out of the Assets section of my Gemfile so I've moved that and deleted my Gemfile.lock and run bundle update.

I've also reinstalled twitter-bootstrap-rails by running

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

I've also made sure that the application.css file has

```
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
```

above

```
*= require_tree .
```

I'm really stumped. Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `config/environments/production.rb` and change the this line from false to true:

```
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true
```

Add, commit, and push the changes.